# How to reference sub-select return value in CASE statement THEN clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm putting together a CASE statement with a sub-select in multiple WHEN clauses that check for null. I would like the corresponding THEN clauses to display whatever was returned by the sub-select.  Is it possible to reference the returned result from a sub-select from the WHEN clause in the THEN clause?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT MAX(Column1) FROM Table1) IS NOT NULL 
            THEN [display the result]
            WHEN (SELECT MAX(Column1) FROM Table2) IS NOT NULL 
            THEN [display the result]
            ELSE 'Unknown' END
FROM dual
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT COALESCE( (SELECT MAX(Column1) FROM Table1),
                 (SELECT MAX(Column1) FROM Table2),
                 'Unknown'
               )
FROM dual;
```

Note:  This assumes that `Column1` is a string.  Otherwise, you might get a type conversion error.